# cannot convert from 'double?' to 'decimal'

Tags: c#, xml, double, converters

I am reading an XML file and I am parsing the information. I am trying to convert the double to an int like this

```
var pruebaPago = Math.Ceiling(row[i].Pagado);
```

but when I run my code I get the following error:

```
cannot convert from 'double?' to 'decimal'
```

The XML file has the following definition for `Pagado`

```
<s:element name="Pagado" type="s:double" nillable="true"/>
```

How can I covert the nillable value and round it the nearest integer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use `Nullable<double>.Value`. You'll also want to check that the value isn't `null` first:

```
if (row[i].Pagado.HasValue)
{
    var pruebaPago = Math.Ceiling(row[i].Pagado.Value);
}
```

The current overload resolution finds the `decimal` overload the best match for `Math.Ceiling`, as you pass a `double?` and not a `double`.

Comment: If he has to have a value anyway, probably better to skip the check and use `GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: @KyleW I'm not sure he actually has a value (since the field is nullable), and `GetValueOrDefault` would yield the default value for double (0.0). I'm not sure that's what he wants.

Comment: Thank you @YuvalItzchakov that is correct, I also had to remember to convert the values to percentages.